# how to check the validation

Tags: c++, c++builder

When I tried to give the string input like "Hello" it is producing an error. How can I check that when I give string input string it should ask me to give correct input?

```
    int y,m,d,h,min,s;
    do
    {
        cout<<" Please enter the year: ";
        cin>>y;
    }while(y < 1970 || y > 2020);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input cannot be converted to a `int` (in your case), then the `failbit` will be set for `std::cin`. This can be retrieved by calling `cin.fail()`.

```
 std::cin >> y;
 if (std::cin.fail()) { 
     std::cout << "data entered is not of int type"; 
 }
```

You can also use `!std::cin` instead of `std::cin.fail()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "iostream"
#include<limits>

using namespace std;

int input()
{
    int y;
    do
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Give the year" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> y;
    }
    while (std::cin.fail() || y < 1970 || y > 2020);
    return y;
}

main()
{
   int x = input();
}
```

Comment: its still showing the error. what i want is that when i give the "Hello" input it should me ask the same question again. But it is asking the question unlimited times, even i cant write anything

Comment: I edited and tested the answer. If that works for you, accept the answer, in order to help others. If not, tell me.